# Running a program written for freeRTOS (RTOS) in virtualmachine as a binary

Tags: embedded, virtual-machine, qemu, rtos, freertos

I got a simple program written for freeRTOS (implements a timer).

I want to run this program in an empty virtual machine (VirtualBox, or QEMU, or something else).

I need to make a binary file that can run in and empty VM.

Any advice or direction of how can i do this?

I checked many stuff on [freeRTOS homepage](http://www.freertos.org/) but couldn't find something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For virtual box, you will need a binary of freeRTOS that is x86 or amd64 compatible. Check if [this](http://www.freertos.org/a00090.html#186) is of any benefit for you.

You can check this [link](http://www.freertos.org/a00090.html#186), as I understand it's a simulator for freeRTOS which may enable you to test it without a virtual machine.

For QEMU, check this [link](https://sudani93.wordpress.com/2015/10/18/simulating-freertos-gem5-or-qemu/)

Answer (score 0):

Emm..., if you need run just binary file without any OS started you can use qemu for that. Just pass your binary through option '-bios' into qemu. And after qemu will start it to run. Also use '-S -s' options in  for enabling gdb server in qemu.  After you can connect to qemu with gdb client and debug you binary step by step.